# MKMapView not responding to touch events or gesture recognizers

Tags: ios, objective-c

**EDIT**:

Immediately after posting this question, I found ONE line of code I missed commenting out.  It was this... `mapViewController.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;`

I commented it out, and the map is working again.

Do you have any idea why that line of code would kill the maps gesture recognizers?

---

I have an MKMapView that was working perfectly fine in recent months, and quit dead today.

The only thing I did today, messing with the code, was to play with some orientation code in `viewWillTransitionToSize:withTransitionCoordinator:` and `viewWillLayoutSubviews`  That's IT !!!
I commented out everything I did there, and still it's dead.

It not only won't respond to my own gesture recognizer, it won't respond to any of its own recognizers... pinch, rotate, etc.  It's just frozen.

I have NO views on top of the map that would obstruct touches either.

I have control-clean(ed) my build folder.

I have closed XCode project and wiped out it's derived data folder for said project.

```
@implementation MapViewController
{
    MKMapView *appleMapView;
}



-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

    [self addMapViewToSelf];
}


-(void)addMapViewToSelf
{
    // Create and add the apple map view to the side menu view.
    appleMapView = [[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
    [self.view addSubview:appleMapView];

    appleMapView.delegate = self;

    UILongPressGestureRecognizer *tapRecognizer = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(windowTapped:)];
    tapRecognizer.minimumPressDuration = 1.0f;
    tapRecognizer.delegate = self;
    [appleMapView addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];
}


-(void)windowTapped:(UIGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    NSLog(@"The recognizer state is '%ld'", (long)recognizer.state);

    if (recognizer.state != UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
        return;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AutoResizingMask is the property by by the UI Elements (eg. Label) shift when the boundaries change. Means when orientation is change the app adapts and does not crash. But if you will set autoResizingMask to Constraint, you are telling it to change constraints as per the autoResizingMask. This is the default behaviour of every UI Element. This helps us to quickly and dynamically arrange UI Elements with methods like self.view.centre or self.view.frame or self.label.size.width etc.

Setting translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO you are actually removing this behaviour. Therefore you must provide the UI Element fixed co-ordinates, so that the UI Element stays there no matter the orientation of screen. But you are not doing so. So the UIElement has no constraints or a fixed location and behave erractically.

You must not set it to NO, if you don't want to play dynamically with UI's location or size. Like input based growing textfield or some crude animation.

Here is Apple trying to tell you the same thing.

> When a view’s bounds change, that view automatically resizes its
>   subviews according to each subview’s autoresizing mask. You specify
>   the value of this mask by combining the constants described in
>   UIViewAutoresizing using the C bitwise OR operator. Combining these
>   constants lets you specify which dimensions of the view should grow or
>   shrink relative to the superview. The default value of this property
>   is UIViewAutoresizingNone, which indicates that the view should not be
>   resized at all.
>
> When more than one option along the same axis is set, the default
>   behavior is to distribute the size difference proportionally among the
>   flexible portions. The larger the flexible portion, relative to the
>   other flexible portions, the more it is likely to grow. For example,
>   suppose this property includes the UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth and
>   UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin constants but does not include
>   the UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin constant, thus indicating
>   that the width of the view’s left margin is fixed but that the view’s
>   width and right margin may change. Thus, the view appears anchored to
>   the left side of its superview while both the view width and the gap
>   to the right of the view increase.
>
> If the autoresizing behaviors do not offer the precise layout that you
>   need for your views, you can use a custom container view and override
>   its layoutSubviews method to position your subviews more precisely.

I do such mistakes a million times , this blog has a nice solution to it.

https://www.innoq.com/en/blog/ios-auto-layout-problem/